# JsonConvert unable to serialize correctly with brackets

Tags: c#, json, jsonconvert, mailchimp-api-v3

I'm trying to post two fields and a bundled object with two fields to Mailchimp's API endpoint.

```
            var store_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpStoreID"];
            var method = String.Format("ecommerce/stores/{0}/products?", store_id);
            var id = "id123";
            var title = "testproduct";
            //var variants = new {id, title };

            var productData = new { id, title, variants = new { id, title } };

            var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productData);
```

When I POST my data and do a try-catch around my code to check, I see that my requestJson returns the following:

```
    {
        "id":"id123",
        "title":"testproduct",
        "variants":{"id":"id123","title":"testproduct"}
    }
```

I **know** the issue is that the variants when serialized isn't returning as `"variants":[{"foo":bar"}]` but how do I resolve it so that my code bundles this as an object correctly?

Second theory: Since C# is a strongly-typed Object Oriented program, do I need to define the objects above with get:sets and then call them into my function?

Comment: Make it a list if you expect [ ]

Comment: Do you want it to be `"variants":[{"foo":bar"}]`?  If so, do something like `var productData = new { id, title, variants = new [] { new { id, title } } };`.  The brackets represent a collection (/array).  To get them, you need a collection or an array of objects (which is what `new [] { }` gives you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write it like this,

```
var productData = new { id, title, variants = new[] {new { id, title }} };
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productData));

//Prints:
{"id":1,"title":"sodijf","variants":[{"id":1,"title":"sodijf"}]}
```

You can use either `dynamic` or an `object` as the type of list as well.

```
var productData = new { id, title, variants = new List<object>() {new { id, title }} };
```

Comment: Thank you all, thanks Jawad for that. The nesting of lists like that was quite confusing.